Can you filter gradio datatables?
Let's say I have this code
import gradio as gr
import pandas as pd

# Sample data for the dataframes
data = {
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35],
    'City': ['New York', 'San Francisco', 'Los Angeles']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define the Gradio interface
def display_data():
    return df, df

iface = gr.Interface(
    fn=display_data,
    inputs=[],
    outputs=[
        gr.DataFrame(interactive=False, label="Non-interactive DataFrame"),
        gr.DataFrame(interactive=True, label="Interactive DataFrame")
    ],
    live=True
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    iface.launch(server_name="0.0.0.0", server_port=7863)

This will show me this

My question is, is there a way I can filter what I see in the datatable? For example show only rows where the city is New York? (well in this case only one row)
